# What is wrong with trying to create two instances of docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, postgres-9.6

I have an idea to up several similar instances with my docker-compose simple mini-project.

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
 postgres:
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: postgres/Dockerfile
   environment:
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
     - POSTGRES_USER=postgres    
   ports:
     - "${PORT_NUMBER}:5432"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:9.6
```

In ./config/.env.dev file I set unique required port number (eg. 5435 for first instance,
5436 for second etc.)

When I up first instance with command:

```
docker-compose -p instance1 --env-file ./config/.env.dev up
```

it's OK and I see one new container and one new network instance1_default.

But when I try to up another new instance with command:

```
docker-compose -p instance2 --env-file ./config/.env.dev up
```

Docker stuck at this:

```
Creating network "instance2_default" with the default driver
```

.. and nothing happens. Yes, I changed port number in env-file before running new instance.

What's wrong with creating new network?

```
Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
```

Comment: Does it not work even with separate `--env-file` for both instances?

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/fb7bf768012094dfb496823cfacafab6). The only change from your above example is that I made 2 env files with different ports and added the project name in there to avoid it on the cmd, and I added an image file name to docker-compose so it builds only once (although there is currently nothing to build....).

Comment: @user14967413 It doesn't work even with separate similar docker-compose files trying up postgres containers on different ports

Comment: @Zeitounator actually in local machine I can't reproduce my issue too. It happens only on my Centos 7 remote server. When I try to up second container suddenly or because of starting second container loses ssh connection to the server. That's the problem. Thanks for your answer!